# SVG are not displayed in StoryBook (React / Vite

Tags: reactjs, svg, vite, storybook

I have an SVG component. It has a lot of SVG and use folder names and file names to pick. It works, but StoryBook doesn't load SVG. All components which use SVG display incorrect. I use Vite. I have no error in StoryBook, just SVG can't be displayed

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { createSvgIconsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-svg-icons';
import { ViteImageOptimizer } from 'vite-plugin-image-optimizer';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['jest', 'testing-library'],
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@import "src/shared/styles/index.scss";',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
    ViteImageOptimizer(),
    createSvgIconsPlugin({
      iconDirs: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/shared/ui/icon/assets')],
      symbolId: 'icon-[dir]-[name]',
    }),
  ],
});
```

**.storybook/main.js**

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react-vite';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-vite',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true,
    defaultName: 'Documentation',
  },
};
export default config;
```

How to solve this problem?

I tried to use `vite-plugin-svg` and refactor config files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you still need it but, here how you can solve it, in your *vite.config.js*

```
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { createSvgIconsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-svg-icons';
import { ViteImageOptimizer } from 'vite-plugin-image-optimizer';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['jest', 'testing-library'],
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@import "src/shared/styles/index.scss";',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr({ include: '**/*.svg' })
    splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
    ViteImageOptimizer(),
    createSvgIconsPlugin({
      iconDirs: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/shared/ui/icon/assets')],
      symbolId: 'icon-[dir]-[name]',
    }),
  ],
});
```

Be sure to install vite-plugin-svgr